# Python - How to turn an IF statement into a Function to call multiple times with other strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, function, if-statement

I need to check whether a permutation of a variable exists in another variable and increment a counter variable if it doesn't exist.

I've managed to create a conditional statement with for loops to make list of required permutations and check whether the variable exists in it. I need to turn it into a function so that i can make the code cleaner as i need the function to check multiple variables across multiple variables.

```
charList = ['A', 'B', 'C'] #actual code has other items in this list

name = "JOHN" #actual variable whose permutations are to be made for checking

checkName = "JOAN" #target variable to check against the permutations of above variable

counter = 0

if checkName is name:
    print('found1')
elif checkName in (name[:i] + c + name[i + 1:] for i in range(len(name)) for c in charList):
    print('found2')
elif checkName in ([name[:i] + c + name[i:] for i in range(len(name)) for c in charList]):
    print('found3')
elif checkName in ([name[0:i] + name[i+1] + name[i] + name[i+2:] for i in range(len(name) - 1)]):
    print('found4')
else:
    counter += 1
    print(counter)
```

How to make it into a function so that just by using another name variable I would directly get output of either the print statement or the increment in the counter?

I'm just a beginner so please help me understand the concept of making functions through this example. I have to deal with two variables one of which loops through a list, and being a noob i have no idea what to do.

P.S. I'm just learning and the above code is just a trial run so please ignore the print functions following each if statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this

```
charList = ['A', 'B', 'C'] #actual code has other items in this list

name = "JOHN" #actual variable whose permutations are to be made for checking

checkName = "JOAN" #target variable to check against the permutations of above variable

def checkName_fun(checkName, name):
    counter = 0

    if checkName is name:        
        return ('found1')
    elif checkName in (name[:i] + c + name[i + 1:] for i in range(len(name)) for c in charList):        
        return ('found2')
    elif checkName in ([name[:i] + c + name[i:] for i in range(len(name)) for c in charList]):        
        return ('found3')
    elif checkName in ([name[0:i] + name[i+1] + name[i] + name[i+2:] for i in range(len(name) - 1)]):        
        return ('found4')
    else:
        counter += 1
        return (counter)

checkName_fun(checkName, name)
```

Comment: Hi nag, thanks for the code. I have a doubt. you initiated counter inside the function, so will i be able to access it and write another if statement based on the value of counter?

Comment: Where do you want to write another if statement. It is available if you are accessing it inside a function. If you want the counter to be available outside the function, you need to capture it as output of function

Comment: The other if statement would be like: 

if counter <= 1: do something 
else: do something else.

It would be after the function is run a few times with different strings. If any string in the whole document satisfies the condition the counter needs to be incremented for each instance and the above condition would then apply.